# Iterate through S3 files in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, iterator, sliding-window

Problem: 
Large number of files. Each file is 10MB and consist of records in json format, gzipped.

My snippet is loading all the data into memory. There is no need to do this. I just need a few hours of data in memory at a time. I need a sliding window.

Is it possible to apply the 'window' idea from spark streaming to the files and how would I do this?

I'm using python

```
location = "s3://bucketname/xxxx/2016/10/1[1-2]/*/file_prefix*.gz"
rdd = sc.textFile(location)
```

Comment: If you know what data needs to loaded , you could use `filter`, since all the transformations in spark are lazy, it loads only the filtered data.

Comment: ok that is really helpful. Still I think I will still end up needing to apply some kind of window. I have a quite a lot of data. It is roughly 300GB gzipped.

Comment: Spark streaming supports Sliding window functionality, check this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations

Comment: You want to apply sliding window concept in Spark Core?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can use `ssc.textFileStream("/file/path")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you posted actually does no computation.  Spark execution is lazy, and only forces computation of "transformations" like `map`s, `filter`s, and even `textFile`s when you ask for a result -- counting the RDD for example.

Another note is that most Spark operations stream by default.  If you have 300 10M json files, you're going to get 300 separate partitions or tasks.  If you're willing to wait, you could perform most RDD operations on this dataset on *one core*.

If you need a sliding window, then there's good functionality for that in the [Spark streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) package.  But the snippet you posted has no problems as it is!